# How can I make my Ajax feed load multiple WordPress posts based upon a post-id div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to loop my jQuery/Ajax script to load two WordPress posts based off of each WordPress post ID in a div tag, so the Ajax URL loads based upon the ID tags.

You can see my example below. I am using the WordPress News blog as an example of the feed.

https://jsfiddle.net/jdcool279/7L361ru0/17/

I figured out how to load one feed based upon the post-id within the  tag, but I can't seem to figure out how to load two feeds via the div tag. To see an example of single feed, please uncomment the script tag within the fiddle. Also, would it be better to change "fetch_comp_content" id tag to a class instead of an id, since I will be needing to include it twice?

Load multiple posts by div post-id:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="container">
    <div id="fetch_comp_content" post-id="6810"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="container">
    <div id="fetch_comp_content" post-id="6848"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Instead of loading 1 post via the script tag:

```
<script title="true" id="comp_cont_init" post-id="6810"></script>
```

I would also like to note that the script tag actually loads the script to run the feed. I did not include that in my fiddle, as I wanted to show the JavaScript code.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quick issues:

1. You can't repeat Id's in a page, they are unique by definition. use
   class instead
2. You aren't making the requests in the `each` loop where you have access to specific element instances and the specific post id's from elements

Here's a minimalistic version of what you are trying to accomplish. All I have rendered is the title for the posts.

Note it is better to use `data-` attributes also

```js
$('.fetch_comp_content').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this),
    postId = $el.data('post-id'),
    urlstring = 'https://wordpress.org/news/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' + postId;

  $.getJSON(urlstring).then(function(data) {
  
    var title = data.title.rendered
    $el.append('<h3>' + title + '</h3>');
    
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log('Bad request')
  })
});
```

```css
.fetch_comp_content { border:2px solid #ccc; margin:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fetch_comp_content" data-post-id="6810"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fetch_comp_content" data-post-id="6846"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @charlietfl